# If statement not sorting and working as expected

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, if-statement

I have a problem with if function.
 I have 3 string arrays ("orderID", "id" and "name")

- orderID contains maximum 10 order numbers.
- id and name are database which contains almost every drink.

I want if "orderID" matches to "id", "name" to be added to the list, if not then string "Not found in database" to be added.

Current code :

```
            string x = "Not found in database";
        for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (string ids in orderID)
            {
                if (ids == id[i])
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(name[i]);
                    listBox2.Items.Add(name[i]);
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(x);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the result:

[image: The result]

Problems:

- 2nd List - when "orderID"  matches to the "id", "name" is added to the list, but not at desired  position. I guess it's adding by position in database. How to avoid that?
- 3rd List is just duplicate  with "else" added. Else it's not working as expected.It's adding "Not found in database" for everything. Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: I can't figure out what list1 and list2 represent, but one thing is that you probably want to add to both list boxes in your else: `else { listBox1.Items.Add(name[i]); listBox2.Items.Add(x); }`; then your list will say , "Cofee, Cofee" for the first one, and "Jack Daniels, Not Found" for the next one, etc.. You may or may not want to reverse your `for` and `foreach` loops, and keep in mind that `break` only breaks out of the inner most loop and your outer one keeps running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested code

```
        var orderIds = new[] {"3", "5"}.ToList();
        var ids = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }.ToList();
        var names = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }.ToList();

        foreach (var orderId in orderIds)
        {                
            if (ids.Contains(orderId))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(names[ids.IndexOf(orderId)]);
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("Not in the list");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I down voted you because I don't think this is a good answer. You have not provided any explanation of what the issue is, how the OP could solve it, and your answer doesn't really resemble the data the OP illustrated.

Comment: @Massanu - I have occured one small problem.
 http://prntscr.com/bukxj5 - Even tough left column have 10 items, right column shows 10 times "Not in the list". Do you know maybe how to fix it?

Comment: Of course if you fix your answer up I will reverse my down vote and possibly even give an up vote :)

Answer (score 0):

> 2nd List - when "orderID" matches to the "id", "name" is added to the
>   list, but not at desired position. I guess it's adding by position in
>   database. How to avoid that?

You can use `OrderBy()` to order your items:

```
List<string> orderedList = list.OrderBy(i => i);
```

This will order them by their content in alphabetical order. If you want to reverse the order you can use `OrderByDescending()`.

> 3rd List is just duplicate with "else" added. Else it's not working as
>   expected.It's adding "Not found in database" for everything. Any
>   suggestion how to fix it?

I’m not sure if your `id` and `orderID` variables are strings or arrays (it would be better to mention it). But in case of arrays you might want to check if desired array **contains** needed `Id` instead of comparing them one-by-one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
            if(orderID.Contains(id[i])
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(name[i]);
                listBox2.Items.Add(name[i]);                     
            }
            else
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(x);
            }
        }
```

And in case of strings you want to just compare them (not symbol by symbol).

Please, name variables correctly and show their type as it would help those who are trying to answer your question.